# Rotating a template to match an edge

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

(I use MATLAB R2015a). I have a plot of edge points of an object (obtained using edge detection), and I have a plot of the template of the object. I want to rotate the template until it matches with the detected edge points. (Figure link included: solid blue - template, red dots - edge detected points; the rotation is subtle, but it's there.)

- I plan to rotate the template in a loop about the centroid through different values of thetas (which **I know** how to do), and ask the code to 'stop executing when it matches with the edge' (which is what I want to know how) and return the corresponding theta.
- The number of points making up the template and that making up the edges are not the same, so splitting the plots into 3 lines and 1 (half) ellipse and directly comparing does not work.
- Using regionprops 'orientation' does not give the expected result for each frame because of the way the edges are being detected in each frame. (I can elaborate more on this if required)
- I have intentionally plotted points using plot, rather than keeping the edge as a BW image because, otherwise, I'm having to round off indices while creating the template, and for my application, I cannot afford to lose precision like that.

[image: Figure]

I'm not lazy, I don't want somebody to just code it up for me. None of my ideas worked and I'm unable to think any differently, so perhaps somebody with a fresh mind and more experience in Matlab will have some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both image and template are bitmaps (= template isn't given as 3x lines + half of ellipse), and you know the position and size of the template, just not the angle:

For each edge, find the closest point on the template, and sum all the distances, or perhaps sum of sqrt of distances, or some other metric that penalizes many small outliers - many points will be slightly wrong if rotation is slightly wrong. Few points that are completely wrong are noise to ignore. So, something like:

```
minDist = inf;
minAngle = -1;
for t = 1 : length(thetas)
templatePoints = ...; % calculate template points.
for i = 1 : length(edges)
    edge = edges(i); % assuming this edge is (x, y) edge point
    mind = inf; % Min distance
    for j = 1 : length(templatePoints)
        d = sum(sqrt((edge - templatePoints).^2));
        if (d < mind)
           mind = d;
        end
    end
end
currentDist = sum(mind);
if (currentDist < minDist)
    ...
end
```

When you complete the full circle of template rotation select the rotation with the lowest difference.

This procedure might be a bit problematic because you might have template rotated by 10.5 deg and you are going in a step of 1 deg, so you will not have totally optimal angle in the end. Plus you will try tons of completely wrong angles, slowing you down. 
But to find the optimal angle you can change angle step, say you first try every 10 deg rotation, then every 1deg around the minimum, then every 0.1deg etc. Or use optimization method. Gradient descent should work fine if you don't have too much noise, use simulated annealing for noisy images. Use the same code as above, currentDist is a good enough optimization parameter - it should be as close to 0 as possible.

If you have unknown template size too, or unknown template position, you definitely should use simulated annealing, gradient descent will almost surely get stuck in a local minimum. Use code similar to above to calculate difference between the edges and template, and put all the unknown parameters to the method.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make an image of your result for each rotation, but do not make it binary, make it grayscale. There are ways of making this so the "maximum interpolated edge" is where your continuous function is (such as [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm), for example).

As you are matching an image, you are not loosing precision, but putting the precision of your target to the same level as your image.

Once you get this, for each rotation, use a metric to evaluate how the 2 grayscale (yes, not binary) images match, using i.e. correlation coefficient, mutual information, universal quality index (UQI), etc.